# need help to save xml display as a document

Tags: javascript, xml

I have written a function in javascript to create XML. I am getting an output through a popped-up window. I want to save this display as a document. How I can save it ? I'm using "alert(xml)" to display the output. i just want to save this display as a document. Please someone help me.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function make_xml() 
{main code            
alert(xml);                 
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title"> <h4>Create XML Report</h4></div>
<div class="box">
Schema name<input type="text" id="name"><br /><br />
Dimensions:<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="dimensions" id="categories">categories<br />
<button type="button" class="btb" onclick="make_xml()">XML erstellen</button>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.
Mirish

Comment: can you post you code so we can work on it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and take a few minutes to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: Not clear what environment you create this in either. If it is in browser will need to send it to server and save it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a data uri and asking the browser to open it in a new window.  Using a type of `application/octet-stream` should force the download but if you are ok with it opening in a new window, go ahead and use `text/xml` or `application/xml`.  You can read up on data uris if you aren't familiar but try the following:

```
var xml = '<whatever>you did to get the xml</whatever>';
var uriContent = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(xml);
var newWindow = window.open(uriContent, 'downloadXmlWindow');
```

There are limitations with the sizes in some browsers and there may be reason to base64 encode (again read up on data uris), but hopefully this gets you headed in the right direction.